# Debug dynamic SQL with print @sql?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamic-sql

I am unable to spot what I did wrong here. I would love to be able to debug this using the print command, but I am unable to get it to work, please point out what I am doing wrong here

```
= " SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;"
+ " DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)"
+ " SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql + N' UNION ', N'') + N'hr.client ,RTRIM(LTRIM(hc.facility)) AS face ,h.gode ,h.rode    ,hr.*"
+ " FROM B1' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), RIGHT(CONCAT('00000',dbname),5)) + '.dbo.herpa h "
+ " JOIN B1' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), RIGHT(CONCAT('00000',dbname),5)) + '.dbo.herpaderpa hr ON hr.[counter] = h.rink "
+ " JOIN B1' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), RIGHT(CONCAT('00000',dbname),5)) + '.dbo.herpacerpa hc ON hc.[counter] = hr.cink " 
+ " WHERE 1=1  "
+ IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!StartDate.Value),"", " AND (hr.r_date > DATEADD(DAY,-1,''"
+ Parameters!StartDate.Value
+ "'')) ")
+ IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!EndDate.Value),"", " AND (hr.r_date < DATEADD(DAY,1,''"
+ Parameters!EndDate.Value
+ "'')) ")


+ " AND hr.NPI IN (''" + Join(Parameters!NPI.Value,"'',''") + "'') "
+ IIf(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!Cat.Value, "ANY") > -1, "", " AND hr.cat IN (''" + Join(Parameters!Cat.Value,"'',''") + "'') ")
+ IIf(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!Gode.Value, "ANY") > -1, "", " AND h.gode IN (''" + Join(Parameters!Gode.Value,"'',''") + "'') ")
+ IIf(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!Rode.Value, "ANY") > -1, "", " AND h.rode IN (''" + Join(Parameters!Rode.Value,"'',''") + "'') ")

+ "' "
+ " FROM (VALUES "
+ Parameters!SC.Value 
+ ") t (dbname) "
+ " exec sp_executesql @sql "
```

I had wrapped the whole thing in an @SQL and then attempted to print @sql
However, that returned nothing. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here

Comment: It is going to be an expression in SSRS, this is the starting point for it. The case issue is purely here (@SQL vs @sql), as i tend to misstype when I get frustrated.  The Result set returned nothing as I have the print command totally wrong. so i didn't put it in here

Comment: This looks pretty complicated. Can you reduce the problem down to 2-3 lines of SQL and post that more concise question? (You will probably answer your own question in the process. If so, please share your solution with others! :-) )

Answer (score 0):

See this section:

```
+ " WHERE 1=1 and "
+ IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!StartDate.Value),"", " AND (hr.r_date > DATEADD(DAY,-1,''"
```

This first line of this *ends* with **`and`**.

On the next line, if the value is not Nothing, a part is added that *starts* with **`AND`**.

Leading to `WHERE 1=1 and AND ...`

Comment: Good catch, but it still blows up with:

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'DS'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)

Comment: I did not look further than this, I'd hope that with this you should be able to look for further (possibly similar) errors in your code.

Comment: I still am, I just don't see any. Thats why I am trying to figure out how to wrap it in a variable and then print it

Comment: Try `Debug.WriteLine(...)` - assuming you run it in Debug mode in Visual Studio

Comment: It can be used in Expressions in SSRS, which I think it is based off of. Not really sure where, I am still trying to get better with it.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot is what this amounts to.

I still have ZERO idea how to wrap this in a Print statement, but I was able to spot the issue.

```
+ " SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql + N' UNION ', N'') + N'hr.client ,RTRIM(LTRIM(hc.facility)) AS face ,h.gode ,h.rode    ,hr.*"
```

should have been

```
+ " SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql + N' UNION ', N'') + N'select hr.client ,RTRIM(LTRIM(hc.facility)) AS face ,h.gode ,h.rode    ,hr.*"
```

Somehow, someway, I forgot the initial select. Apparently I am an idiot

Comment: Thanks for sharing, and mistakes are easy to make as we all know!